# Cannot get results to appear fro PHP function

Tags: php, html-table

I for the life of my cannot figure out why my table isn't displaying results. It's acting as the values but no text appears. I need to display only the type of food based on user choice.


The Array

```
$aList = array ();
$aList[0] = array();
$aList[0]['Animal'] = "Bear";
$aList[0]['Habitat'] = "Forest";
$aList[0]['Food'] = "Meat";


$aList[1] = array();
$aList[1]['Animal'] = "Deer";
$aList[1]['Habitat'] = "Forest";
$aList[1]['Food'] = "Grass";

$aList[2] = array();
$aList[2]['Animal'] = "Pig";
$aList[2]['Habitat'] = "Farm";
$aList[2]['Food'] = "Mixed";

$aList[3] = array();
$aList[3]['Animal'] = "Cow";
$aList[3]['Habitat'] = "Farm";
$aList[3]['Food'] = "Grass";

$aList[4] = array();
$aList[4]['Animal'] = "Sheep";
$aList[4]['Habitat'] = "Farm";
$aList[4]['Food'] = "Grass";

$aList[5] = array();
$aList[5]['Animal'] = "Camel";
$aList[5]['Habitat'] = "Desert";
$aList[5]['Food'] = "Grass";

$aList[6]['Animal'] = "Scorpion";
$aList[6]['Habitat'] = "Desert";
$aList[6]['Food'] = "Meat";
```

The Function

```
function showList($Food){
        // Use the global keyword to tell the PHP engine to find the variable $classList outside of the function.  Without this, the PHP engine will only look for $classList inside a function.

        global $aList;

        // Set up a variable $tbl to store the HTML output (class list table)
        // Note that the <table></table> tags and the table header row are outside of the foreach loop so that they are not repeated in each iteration of the loop.

        $tbl = "<table border=1>";
        $tbl = $tbl."<tr><th>Animal</th><th>Habitat</th><th>Food</th></tr>";

        foreach ($aList as $Animal){
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $food = strtolower($_POST['Food']);
                    if (strtolower($Animal['Food']) == $food)
                    $tbl .= "<tr><td>{$Animal[$food.'Animal']}</td><td>{$Animal[$food.'Habitat']}</td><td>{$Animal[$food.'Food']}</td></tr>";
            }

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $habitat = strtolower($_POST['Habitat']);
                if (strtolower($Animal['Habitat']) == $habitat)
                    $tbl .= "<tr><td>{$Animal[$habitat.'Animal']}</td><td>{$Animal[$habitat.'Habitat']}</td><td>{$Animal[$habitat.'Food']}</td></tr>";

            }

        }
    $tbl .= "</table>";
    echo $tbl;
}
```

Comment: You don't actually produce any output

Comment: Your function doesn't echo or return `$tbl`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `$Food` argument? You don't use it anywhere in the function.

Comment: Sorry guys I mustve not copied and pasted the echo....fixed it now though.


I and @Barmar I guess I dont really know what the purpose of the argument would be, can I create the function without an argument?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish with `$Animal[$food.'Animal']`? your array key is just `Animal`. there no prefix.

Comment: @Marc B I'm not exactly sure, I thought it was going to tell the function to display the type of animal there.

Comment: then it'd be `echo $Animal['Food']`. `$food . 'Animal'` would be doing something like `echo $Anima['applePig']`, which doesn't exist in your array.

Comment: OH so you're saying I don't need all the extra $food in the table datas?

Comment: You don't need to repeat that `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`. Do it once and combine those two parts if you are using those both parts.

Comment: @MarcB 
Thank you so much!!!! It Worked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of `$Animal[$food.'Animal']` in your loop but in your array it is just `$Animal['Animal']`. You are concatenating the food variable to the key but your array does not have any other keys then Animal, Habitat, and Food. So you will need to take all the $food and $habitat variables out of the key value in your `$Animal` array.

Comment: This worked thank you so much!!!